# Re-running docker-compose in Windows says network configuration changed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose version 1.11.2 on Windows and using a version 2.1 docker-compose.yml but whenever I try to run something like `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose run` a subsequent time, I get an error that the network needs to be recreated because configuration options changed (even if I didn't change anything). I can `docker network rm` to remove the network, but from other documentation and posts about docker-compose on Linux it seems this is unnecessary.

I can reproduce this reliably but can't really find any further information. Can anyone explain why I keep getting errors to recreate the network (using a transparent driver to download some stuff when building the image, but even using the nat driver gives me a similar error) or at least how to work around it? One of my scenarios is to be able to use `docker-compose run` on one of the services a couple of times on the same machine as part of cloud build/test.

Comment: I was facing the same and did not know about the `docker network rm`... again, SO to the rescue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug and was fixed in a subsequent update several weeks ago. I was told by one of the Docker developers that Windows 10 Creators Update was required as well.